# Datatype error in teradata

Tags: teradata

i export the netezza table records into csv file with time format column 00:00:00 and import the csv file data into teradata table. But my records are not inserted in teradata because of time datatype. In csv files i use varchar datatype for time column in unix script and use time datatype for teradata. I want to know the reason for why records not inserted in teradata tables.

Comment: How are you importing the data into Teradata? Are you using TD Parallel Transporter, conventional Fastload or through SQL Assistant / TD Studio? Sharing the exact error returned by the utility will help. In case the utility does not give an error, check if any error tables are created in Teradata.

Comment: i am importing the data using fastload script only

Comment: What is the error that you are getting? Can you share the output log?

Comment: 06:44:03 Number of recs/msg: 1
**** 06:44:03 Starting to send to RDBMS with record 1
**** 06:44:03 Sending row 2516
**** 06:44:03 ERRLIMIT exceeded
    Logoff/Disconnect

Comment: What is your checkpoint count? It appears that there are records in the file which violate the defined schema because the error appears after multiple rows are sent to RDBMS. I don't think this issue has anything to do with `Time` data type. Check if there are commas appearing in data messing up the delimiter count.

Comment: You can print out that specific line from your CSV file and look at the actual values.  Then you can parse it to make sure it it has expected number of columns, etc.  Also, is that the only error you're getting back?

Comment: Any format defined in the target table for date/time field, which does not fit the data in the file?  Are there quoted fields, or optional quoted fields? Then you should/must switch to TPT.